# How to Apache rewriting URL rules using %{REQUEST_URI} and negation for Nginx?

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

Here are my current Apache rules in *site.conf*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

How do I convert this to Nginx rewriting rules ?